# Google App Script Typescript and Jest Testing - Mocking GoogleAppScript Object not working for me: What is the best approach here?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, ts-jest

I am working in my local environment with clasp and typescript.

I read already this posts:

- [Testing with Jest and Typescript using Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632801/testing-with-jest-and-typescript-using-mocks)
- [How to mock dependencies when testing GAS with CLASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428746/how-to-mock-dependencies-when-testing-gas-with-clasp)

But that did not fully work out for me.

As in my (typescript) class I need to import as follows:

```js
import CalendarApp = GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.CalendarApp
import Calendar = GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.Calendar

export default class someService{
...
}
```

When I do the test (in my doTests.test.ts typescript file) I try to mock `GoogleAppScript` as mentioned in one of the other postings:

```js
// @ts-ignore
global.GoogleAppsScript = {
    // @ts-ignore
    Calendar: () => {
        CalendarApp: () => ({})
        Calendar: () => ({})
    }
}

test( ... ) //testing to create an instance of someService
```

And still getting the error:

```sh
● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: GoogleAppsScript is not defined

    > 6 | import CalendarApp = GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.CalendarApp;
        |                      ^
```

What did I get wrong here?

**UPDATE**

What I also tried now, was to configure globals in the jest config:

```
globals: {
     GoogleAppsScript: {
       Calendar: {
           Calendar: () => {},
           CalendarApp: () => {}
         }
       }
   },
```

Now the problem was solved, but I am not sure if this was the right approach. If this gets more complex, and it will, I have I need to deal with that separation of mocks in the config.

Any best practice suggestions for that?

Comment: Using `globals` looks O.K. to me. One small note is that `Calendar` and `CalendarApp` are supposed to be plain objects too, though